# Firebase callable function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is the portion of my `index.js` file:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Firebase Setup
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const sanitizedMessage = sanitizer.sanitizeText("test");
    return admin.database().ref('/messages').push({
        text: sanitizedMessage
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('New Message written');
        return { text: sanitizedMessage };
    })
});
```

This function is successfully uploaded to Firebase. I am trying to call it from my web client using this code:

```
var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
addMessage({text: "test"}).then(function(result) {
    var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
    console.log(sanitizedMessage);
});
```

The result is an error with the following description:

[image]

In addition, there is no log in the Firebase console. If I visit the link directly, I do, however, get a log message. Which implies two things:

1. The URL of my function is constructed correctly by my web client.
2. Given that visiting it directly produces a log in the Firebase console, it means that my web client doesn't even make this call.

I am completely stuck as I have followed the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Any help in debugging this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which sanitizer package are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const sanitizedMessage = sanitizer.sanitizeText("test");
    return admin.database().ref('/messages').push({
        text: sanitizedMessage
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('New Message written');
        return { text: sanitizedMessage };
    })
});
```

Comment: I will give it a try though I do not see any difference from my original code which could explain the original error. Could you maybe elaborate on what is so different in this code that it’ll work? Also, why do you initialise the app without a service account? Surely, this cannot work?

Comment: you dont need service account if you deploy in the cloud functions of same project

Comment: I've rewritten the code as you suggested and the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and tested your code thoroughly and there may be two problems.

I make the assumption that you intent to use this npm sanitizer package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitizer, therefore these problem might be:

1. You don't require the sanitizer package. (have you installed it, btw?)
2. `sanitizeText` is not a method of the sanitazer module, while `sanitize` is

The following code works well:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const sanitizer = require('sanitizer');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const sanitizedMessage = sanitizer.sanitize("test");
    console.log(sanitizedMessage);

    return admin.database().ref('/messages').push({
        text: sanitizedMessage
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('New Message written');
        return { text: sanitizedMessage };
    })
});
```